# Trying to hide my drop down menu in default

Tags: jquery, html, css, interface

I'm trying to figure out on how i can hide my drop down menu by default. Basically it shows up at the start. The drop down menu on "My Account"

[image]

Here is my HTML

```
           <li class="hoverli"><a  href="/customer/account">My Account</a>

                    <ul class="user-account">

                       <li><a href="">edit my account</a></li>

                       <li id="wish"><a href="">my wishlist</a></li>

                       <li id="gift"><a href="">my gift registry</a></li>

                    </ul>

                 </li>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".hoverli").hover(
      function () {
         jQuery('.user-account').slideDown('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
         jQuery('.user-account').slideUp('slow');
      }
    );
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a css rule

```
.user-account {
    display: none
}
```

or hide it using jQuery on page load

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $ua = jQuery('.user-account').hide(); //cache the selector since it is used multiple times
    jQuery(".hoverli").hover(
      function () {
         $ua.slideDown('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
         $ua.slideUp('slow');
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use Java-Script when the same can be accomplished with CSS, as in the following examples:

```
.user-account {
    display: none;
}

li:hover .user-account {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

if you want animation :

```
.user-account {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top : -100%;
    transition: top 2s ease-in-out;
    z-index:0;
}

li:hover .user-account {
    display: inline-block;
    top : -100%;
}
```

Would javascript offer any advantages in these cases?